# Problem getting the whole object from Entity Framework when requesting via API methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor, rider

I have a problem with the API requests. I'm trying to get the whole object from the server to the client, it is retrieved, but without some fields.

[This is what it should get for job object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHE03.png), but the problem is that it is returned with null values: [see photo-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlPBp.png)

I mention that adult has that specific job: [see photo-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiKwY.png)

I tried also to rebuild the migrations, database or also to add a DbSet for everything that the object has, but nothing.

Having this problem, I can't update or remove the object.

What should it be?

Comment: I'll leave also the whole project, if this helps with something: https://github.com/BaicoianuIoanSorin/DNPAssignment3
Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you add a picture of your DB diagram to the question? It looks like you have a relationship that you do not include in the EF query. It would also be useful to add the code directly in the answer. Bine ai venit pe SO :) [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: After crawling for a bit through your code, in your `Adult` class, you only have `Job JobTitle` but I believe you should also have `int JobId`, the foreign key. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#definition-of-terms).

Comment: @Grizzlly Multumesc :3! Unfortunately I don't have any DB diagram made.
I tried also to add a JobId and specify that is a foreign key, but nothing.
After debugging a few times, I realized that my class **Adult** initializes **Job** in the constructor. So probably, once I get the whole object, it finds the right credentials for **Job** object, but, because **Adult** initializes it as being without any credentials, request method gets it null.

Comment: Maybe the problem lies in how you create your context, as I assume this is a code-first approach. Please go through [the link I have referenced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) that should solve your problem. The question is missing a lot of details. [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the entity class definitions for your Adult and Job/JobTitle classes. The cause is likely either that you don't have a many-to-one relationship properly mapped between the two, or you have disabled lazy loading and have done something like:

```
public class Adult
{
    // ....


    public Job JobTitle { get; set; } = new Job();
}
```

Which would see EF load an Adult but have an initialized empty job title. You should only initialize one-to-many collections.

The mapping can be done either by Attribute, EntityTypeConfiguration, or modelBuilder in the DbContext OnModelCreating. Basing assumptions on your model it should look something like:

```
public class Adult
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Other properties...

    [ForeignKey("JobTitleIdJob")]
    public virtual Job JobTitle { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    [Key]
    public int IdJob { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

The FK on JobTitle above uses a shadow property, alternatively you can define the FK field in Adult as well, but the FK relationship needs to be explicitly mapped since the column name does not conform to the naming convention of the type. (I.e. JobId or Job_Id)

If your relationships are set up properly then eager loading the job title can be done when loading the Adult(s).

```
var adult = context.Adults
    .Include(x => x.Job)
    .Single(x => x.Id == adultId);
```